# Is there any version of PyCrypto for android

Tags: android, python, pycrypto

i'm writing an encryption and brute force attack on different algorithms in python using PyCrypto.
in order to test them and get some data to see how would they perform when used in RFID applications.
the only device that i can test for now is raspberry pi. and i wanted to run my program on other devices equipped with RFID/NFC capabilities in order to have a broader range of data
im trying to run my program on a samsung galaxy nexus running android 4.4.2, the python client works fine, but the problem is the program imports from PyCrypto which is not installed 
i have installed some version of pycrypto from [the link provided by Google](https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/downloads/detail?name=pycrypto-2.3-py2.7-linux-armv.egg&can=2&q=) and still with no luck
is there any way i can run my program on android ??